# "speak English" vs "speak in English"

Tags: prepositions, transitivity, redundancy

> I don't get the chance to speak **in** English often.

I've been told **in** doesn't need to be in this sentence, but does its inclusion make the sentence grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sentence is correct with or without "in".

It's subtle, but there is a slight difference in meaning between the two.

With "*the chance to speak English*", "speak" is a *transitive verb* and "English" is the direct object. The intent is to use English itself, like a student who wants to practice. Communication may not be important at all.

With "*the chance to speak **in** English*", "speak" is *intransitive*, so it just means "communicate", and the communication happens to be in English. An English native speaker who lives in a country where nobody speaks English might say this if they happen to meet a fellow English speaker because they're talking about the experience of communicating using English.

Answer (score 4):

It is grammatical with or without the *in*.

In most cases we would not use the *in*, but we could do, especially when we were talking not about the person's ability, but about their choice at a particular time. I don't think there's a context where we must use *in*.

By the way: the title of your question is ungrammatical. You need either  *Is using "in" in the given sentence grammatically incorrect?* or *Does using "in" in the given sentence make it grammatically incorrect?*. With a lexical verb "make" in base form, the auxiliary must be "does".